# C: corrupted pointer from push function?

Tags: c, associative-array

I'm having trouble with a pointer that changes value as its passed to a function… I have various print statements scattered throughout that confirm that the value of the pointer doesn't change, just node->prev in hashmap, which causes me to lose the list and crash the program because I expect it to be valid or 0. Print statements indicate the pointer value changes when its passed to `pushmap`.

I'm curious how this is possible:

where it all starts: closure:

```
RELATION * closure(RELATION * list, RELATION * testdep, DEP_HOLDER * deplist)
{
    RELATION *ret = 0;
    if(list && testdep && deplist)
    {
        HASHMAP * top=buildmap(deplist);
        ret = copyrelation(testdep);
        traversehashmap(ret,top);
     }
     return ret;
}
```

buildmap:

```
HASHMAP * buildmap(DEP_HOLDER * deplist)
{
    HASHMAP * ret = 0;
    if(deplist)
    {
        while(deplist)
        {
            DEPENDENCY *dd = deplist->data;
            HASHMAP * nnew = 0;
            nnew = createhashmap(dd->left);
            if(ret)
            {
                pushmap(&ret, nnew);    
            }
            else
            {
                ret = nnew;
            }
            RELATION *holder = dd->right;
            while(holder)
            {
                RELATION * h = getnewrelation(holder->data);
                HASHNODE *node = createhashnode(h);
                if(ret->determines)
                {
                    pushnode(&(ret->determines), node); 
                }
                else
                {
                    ret->determines=node;
                }
                holder=holder->next;
            }
            deplist=deplist->next; 
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

pushmap and pushnode:

```
void pushmap(HASHMAP **top, HASHMAP **nnew)
{
    (*top)->prev=(*nnew);
    (*nnew)->next=(*top);
    *top=*nnew;
}
void pushnode(HASHNODE **top,HASHNODE *nnew)
{
    nnew->next=(*top);
    *top=nnew;
}
```

the hashmap and hashnode creation functions just in case:

```
HASHMAP * createhashmap(RELATION * value)
{
    HASHMAP *ret = (HASHMAP *)malloc(sizeof(HASHMAP *));
    ret->value=value; ret->visited=0; ret->prev=0;
    ret->next=0; ret->determines=0;
    return ret;
}
HASHNODE * createhashnode(RELATION * value)
{
    HASHNODE *ret = (HASHNODE *)malloc(sizeof(HASHNODE *));
    ret->value=value; ret->next=0;
return ret;
}
```

EDIT: this was the problem:
turn out this:

```
HASHMAP *ret = (HASHMAP *)malloc(sizeof(HASHMAP *));
```

should be:

```
HASHMAP *ret = (HASHMAP *)malloc(sizeof(HASHMAP));
```

Comment: `HASHMAP *ret = (HASHMAP *)malloc(sizeof(HASHMAP *));` should be `HASHMAP *ret = (HASHMAP *)malloc(sizeof(HASHMAP));` heh.

Comment: you can edit your own question...

Comment: Is that what you meant?

Comment: Not sure, are you saying that that is the answer?

Comment: You should best post your answer as an actual answer (there should be a "answer your question" button) and then mark that answer as accepted. This will make it immediately clear to everybody that you already solved it and what the solution was. Otherwise people first have to read through the whole question to only find out in the end that the problem is already solved.

Comment: You could have avoided this error by using the idiom `T *ptr = malloc( sizeof *ptr );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out this:

```
HASHMAP *ret = (HASHMAP *)malloc(sizeof(HASHMAP *));
```

should be:

```
HASHMAP *ret = (HASHMAP *)malloc(sizeof(HASHMAP));
```